# Unable to reset the state using react-router-dom Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I have a `SearchBar` component where I have this `Link` which on click takes me to a `ProductSearchScreen` which display a set of products associated with a category.

```
return (
  <Link to={{ pathname:# somepath, search: `searchItem=${category.name}` }}>
    {category.name}
  </Link>
)
```

In my `ProductSearchScreen`, I have checkboxes which filter out the data such as "category", "brand" filter etc...

For filtering out categories for example, I have this code

```
const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState(queryParams.get('categories')?.split(',') ?? []);

<input
  type="checkbox"
  checked={selectedCategories.includes(category)}
  onClick={() => handleCategories(category)}
/>
```

The issue is, suppose I'm in `ProductSearchScreen` of `category1` and have few checkboxes clicked and in searchBar I type `category2` and navigate to `category2` page, the checkboxes still remain `checked` for `category2`.

Though I don't have anything in `queryParams` on navigate, it is not resetting the state of `selectedCategories`.
How can I make sure the checkboxes are not checked on navigating to another page?

Edit:
This is the component consuming the path and querystring

```
function ProductSearchScreen() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [queryParams] = useSearchParams();

    // Here is the queryString i am getting
    const category = queryParams.get('searchItem'); 
    const categories = queryParams.get('categories')?.split(',');
    const uniqueCategories = getUniqueCategories(products)

    // with axios call, i get the list of products and update the state like setProducts(products).

    // This is a helper function to filter the categories
    const filterCategories = (product) => {
        if(categories?.length > 0) {
            return categories?.includes(product.category);
        } else {
            return product
        }
    }

    const filteredAndSortedProducts = products?.filter(filterCategories)

    return ( <Filters uniqueCategories={uniqueCategories}/> )
}
```

```
function Filters({ uniqueCategories }) {
    const [queryParams, setQueryParams] = useSearchParams();
    const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState(queryParams.get('categories')?.split(',') ?? []);

    const handleCategories = (category) => {
        if (selectedCategories.includes(category)) {
            setSelectedCategories(selectedCategories.filter((c) => c !== category));
        } else {
            setSelectedCategories([...selectedCategories, category]);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div key={index} className="filter-type">
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                disabled={queryParams.get('categories')?.split(',').includes(category)}
                checked={selectedCategories.includes(category)}
                onChange={() => handleCategories(category)}
            />
            <div className="filter-item">{category}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using? Can you also [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] of the component code consuming the path + queryString?

Comment: Hi, i'm using 6.1.0 version of react-router-dom. And also updated the component code. Please let me know if further details are required

Comment: What state in `ProductSearchScreen` are you needing to reset? The original edit mentions a `selectedCategories` state, but I don't see that in the `ProductSearchScreen` component. Is this a complete [mcve]?

Comment: The `selectedCategories` is the array of checkbox inputs which I want to reset on navigate. I forgot to include one more component while editing. Have updated now

Comment: Ok, I see now, `selectedCategories` is in the `Filters` component. Where is `queryParams` defined in `Filters`?

Comment: I have the queryParams defined like `const [queryParams, setQueryParams] = useSearchParams();` in Filters. Did not edit it thinking its obvious i've included :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253828/discussion-between-srivatsa-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Filters` component only checks the query params once when it mounts. If it needs to react to changes in the `"categories"` query params then it should also implement a lifecycle hook, e.g. `useEffect`, to update the `selectedCategories`.

```
function Filters({ uniqueCategories }) {
  const [queryParams, setQueryParams] = useSearchParams();
  const categories = queryParams.get('categories');

  const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState(categories?.split(',') ?? []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedCategories(categories?.split(',') ?? []);
  }, [categories]);

  ...

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Note that when you see that you've written a `useState`/`useEffect` combo that you may actually just need the `useMemo` hook.

```
function Filters({ uniqueCategories }) {
  const [queryParams, setQueryParams] = useSearchParams();
  const categories = queryParams.get('categories');

  const selectedCategories = useMemo(() => {
    return categories?.split(',') ?? [];
  }, [categories]);

  ...

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

Comment: This solution works! But i also tried and this also works. I'm confused if my try is a good solution or not ?
```<Link to=... state={{ resetFilters: true }} />
```
And in Filters, i did this
```const location = useLocation();
useEffect(() => { if (location.state && location.state.resetFilters) { setSelectedCategories([]); }}, [location]);
```

Comment: @Srivatsa Ah, yeah, that could work as well, though it sort of loosely couples the component rendering the link to the component it's linking to, but it's not terrible in this case.

Comment: @Srivatsa Right, it's better (IMO) to not rely on external callers to remember to pass that `resetFilters` link state.

Comment: In your solution using `useMemo`, how will i be able to set the state for `selectedCategories` in `handleCategories` function ?

Comment: @Srivatsa Ah, sorry, I hadn't caught that `handleCategories` was also updating `selectedCategories`. In this case it might be better to go with the first suggestion. If you like the `useMemo` version then `handleCategories` could just mutate the `queryParams` object and call `setQueryParams` to update the URL queryString. The component will rerender and recompute the `selectedCategories` value. Basically this treats the `queryParams` as the "single source of truth".

Comment: Ok got it! I'll go ahead with the first option as it looks viable to me.